# Unterschied zwischen sich rüsten und sich vorbereiten

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

> Ich bereite mich auf meine Matheprüfung vor.
>
> Ich rüste mich für die Matheprüfung.

Haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung in diesem Kontext?

Comment: Anderes Register. Und das Register von _rüsten_ paßt gar nicht gut mit dem saloppen _Mathe_ zusammen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sich rüsten* ist in einer ähnlichen Kategorie wie *sich wappnen*. Beide beinhalten zwar ein *sich auf etwas vorbereiten*, aber es schwingt eine gewisse Verteidigungshaltung mit.

Beispiel:

> Hast Du keine Angst vor Grippe?
>   Nein, ich bin geimpft und damit gut dagegen gewappnet.

*Sich vorbereiten* bedeutet lediglich, dass man Dinge bezüglich eines zukünftigen Ereignisses unternimmt, jedoch ohne eine Aussage darüber zu treffen, ob das Ereignis potenziell schädlich ist.

Im Gegensatz zu *sich rüsten* oder *sich wappnen* wird *sich vorbereiten* auch in dem in der Frage verwendeten Sinne gebraucht. In diesem Satz liegt es im Bereich von *lernen* oder *studieren*, ist aber allgemeiner für alle Tätigkeiten, die der Vorbereitung dienen:

*ich lerne für die Matheprüfung* bedeutet normalerweise, dass man am Schreibtisch sitzt und wirklich dafür arbeitet.

*Ich bereite mich auf die Matheprüfung vor* kann aber auch einfach bedeuten, dass man erstmal die Unterlagen sichtet und sortiert, dann prüft, woran man noch arbeiten muss, etc.

*sich vorbereiten* kann also in diesem Kontext viele Tätigkeiten umfassen, welche zielführend sind, unter anderem auch *lernen*.

Man kann aber auch folgendes sagen:

> Bereit für die Mathe-Prüfung?
>   Ich habe Cola, Dextro-Energen und einen Stift - ich bin gerüstet.

Das hat dann aber nichts mit der Vorbereitung zu tun sondern enspricht der Aussage *Ich glaube ich habe alles, was ich brauche*/*ich bin bereit*.